# keytool error: java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 45

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, x509

I have got the error as "***keytool error: java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 45***" when I am importing a Self Signed certificate into the certificate file "**cacerts**" which is available in the jre library.

The command am using to import the certificate is "*keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore D:\User\KotakTPINSSL.cer -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore D:\User\certfile\cacerts -deststoretype JKS"*

I have also gone through the link [Push notification - Caused by: java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525388/push-notification-caused-by-java-io-ioexception-toderinputstream-rejects-tag)  but that does not suits with this problem.

Can someone tell me the alternative command to import the certificate? or Is there any other thing that I need to do?

Comment: The solution is given in your link. A .cer file is not a PKCS12 keystore.

Comment: Thanks.I have tried after removing the store type "srcstoretype" as "PKCS12"."keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore D:\User\KotakTPINSSL.cer -destkeystore D:\Nivetha\Original\cacerts -deststoretype JKS". Now the error is "keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format"

Comment: If your task is *importing a Self Signed certificate*, why do you use **importkeystore** and not **importcert**?