# toDerInputStream rejects tag type 123

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to run the Get started with Datastore example at https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/ trying it both from the command line and from Eclipse.

In both environments, it is not able to connect to datastore and gives an I/O error message 'toDerInputStream rejects tag type 123'.

Looking around, this may be because the private key file is in json format and perhaps it should the p12 - other than that the error message draws a blank.

Could anyone point to something that would help me past this?

Comment: Can you copy the stack trace?

Comment: java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 123
 at sun.security.util.DerValue.toDerInputStream(DerValue.java:847)
 at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1915)
 at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
 at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:82)
 at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:115)
 at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(GoogleCredential.java:671)
.
.
.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use PKCS#12 format, as you said, p12. There's a few other people with similar errors (although they're trying to accomplish different things). I hope this helps, let us know if it resolves the issue.

[Push Notification in Java expect p12 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387191/java-apns-apple-push-notification-service-error)

[toDerInputSteam rejects tag 66](https://code.google.com/p/javapns/issues/detail?id=26)